# In linux platform, Hibernate validation error says "found int(11) expected big int". But works fine in windows

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, validation, spring-data-jpa

I think this is fairly common problem and I have gone through various stackoverflow questions related to this type of error. So I know, how to fix this error, but I am more interested to know why this is happening only when I try to build the project in ubuntu, but works fine in windows. First let me write down my configurations and dependencies.

Configuration bean for entityManagerFactory:

```
Properties additionalJpaProperties() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "validate");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    return properties;
}

@Bean
@DependsOn("flywayMigration")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    factory.setJpaProperties(additionalJpaProperties());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.zobayer.stock.core.entities");
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

Relevant project dependencies (just to show the versions of artifacts I am using):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.36</version>
    </dependency>
```

A sample entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ACCOUNTS")
public class Account implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    private String accountNumber;

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_DETAILS")
    private String accountDetails;

    // setters and getters
}
```

Table schema for Accounts:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `accounts` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `account_number` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `account_details` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=2;
```

#### The problem:

As I have the id field of type int(11), and I am using **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** set to **validate**, when I try to build the project artifact on my Ubuntu machine, it gives me validation error like:

```
... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [ID] in table [ACCOUNTS]; found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [bigint (Types#BIGINT)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateColumnType(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:105) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.validateTable(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:92) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaValidatorImpl.doValidation(SchemaValidatorImpl.java:50) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:91) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:484) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:802) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.1.Final.jar:5.0.1.Final]
... 74 common frames omitted
```

But the project can be built without any problem in Windows. Is this because of some MySQL settings? I know how to avoid this problem, we can use columnDefinition="INT(11)") or update the database schema, and I want to know how to solve it without changing the code or schema of the project.

Comment: 2^31, what fits in a 32 bit int, allows but INT(9), 2 ^9.  My guess is that Linux uses 32 bit whereas Windows uses a 64 bits C int.. On the java side only long would fit.

Comment: Both my windows and linux are 64 bit machines, and also, I am using java 1.8 in both os, and JVM arch-type is 64 bit as well.